# CollectionView with different number of items, items should fill the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, width, collectionview

I have a scenario that I have X Labels (or Buttons). They should appear in a horizontal collection view. There shouldn't be scrollable. The thing is that the number of lables/buttons can change (0-5).

The perfect thing would be to use a StackView with equal width for every item but I can't use that, because it needs iOS 9. (I need compatibility for iOS 8.0 too -.-)

So I build a collection view, disabled to scroll and want to set a dynamically height and width for my cells.

I get the height/width of my collectionView

```
heightOfLabel = testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.height
widthOfLabel = testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.width / 
                   CGFloat(array5.count)
```

The results are testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.width = 568.0
widthOflabel 113.6 
array5 = 5 items

I used this method to size my cells:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

     let c = CGSizeMake(heightOfLabel!, widthOfLabel!);
     return c
  }
```

He should size the cells to width 113.6 and 33.0
But it looks like this: [image]

I tried a little bit with Aspect Fit, Scale to Fill etc. but it doesn't change so much. It is too big or too small. [image]

Does anybody has an idea? I would use another technology than collection View, too.

> when did i store the values in my variables?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    testModeLoginCollectionView.delegate = self
    testModeLoginCollectionView.dataSource = self

    heightOfLabel = testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.height
    widthOfLabel = testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.width / CGFloat(array5.count)
    print("testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.width \(testModeLoginCollectionView.frame.width)")
    print("widthOfLabel \(widthOfLabel)")

}
```

I tried it in viewDidAppear to, but no difference

Comment: At what point are you storing the values for heightOfLabel and widthOfLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after viewDidLayoutSubviews view have right frame.
so you can in viewDidLayoutSubviews reloadData.
but i have another solution:you could use https://github.com/forkingdog/FDStackView 
it's have same api like uistackview

Comment: interesting i will have a look